# Upload a pdf file via url for android using phonegap

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, upload

I want to upload an pdf file from an url. if the user enters the url or the sdcard path in field and press submit button the pdf has to be uploaded. Recently i did an image upload by viewing an sample. i am a new bie to phonegap so can any body can help me how to do this